# Proving that the distance between a point and the median intersection point is $\le$ than 1/3 the sum of distances between the point and vertexes

Tags: geometry, vectors, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> Given a triangle $ABC$. The point $M$ is the median intersection point. $O$ is an arbitrary point. How can I prove that $$OM \le \frac{OA + OB + OC}{3}?$$

I think that first we need to prove that $\vec{OM} = \vec {OA} + \vec{OB} + \vec {OC}$.

Comment: By median intersection point, do you mean that a median is drawn from say $A$ to $BC$, and the point of it's contact with $BC$ is taken as $M$?

Comment: No. It is the intersection point of all three medians of the triangle.

Comment: Oh, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: In the equality you have to prove, on RHS you have the coefficient $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{cyc}\vec{AM}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\vec{AB}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\vec{AB}=\vec{0}.$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{cyc}\vec{OA}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\vec{OM}-\vec{AM}\right)=3\vec{OM},$$
which says
$$OM=\left|\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\vec{OA}\right|\leq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\left|\vec{OA}\right|=\frac{OA+OB+OC}{3}$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I really am. The problem is solved this way:
$$\vec{OM}=\vec{OA}+\vec{AM}$$
$$\vec{OM}=\vec{OB}+\vec{BM}$$
$$\vec{OM}=\vec{OC}+\vec{CM}$$

So $\;3\cdot \vec{OM}=\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}+(\vec{AM}+\vec{BM}+\vec{CM})$.

Now $\vec{AM}+\vec{BM}+\vec{CM}=0\,.\;$ It's all trivial. Sorry for misleading you. (I deleted a bad idea that overcame me). So we get this $\;3\cdot \vec{OM}=\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}\,,\;$and $\;3\cdot OM\leqslant OA+OB+OC\,.$

PS for example, it's obvious that $\vec{AM}=1/3(\vec{AC}+\vec{AB})\,.\;$ And we get similar expressions for vectors $\,\vec{BM}\,$ and $\,\vec{CM}\,.\,$ They then will all cancel out when we add them up $\vec{AC}+\vec{CA}=0$ etc. In other words we get:

$\vec{BM}=1/3(\vec{BA}+\vec{BC})\,,\quad$
$\vec{CM}=1/3(\vec{CA}+\vec{CB})\,.\quad$

Hence,
$\;\vec{AM}+\vec{BM}+\vec{CM}=\frac{1}{3}(\vec{AC}+\vec{AB}+\vec{BA}+\vec{BC}+\vec{CA}+\vec{CB})=0\,.$

This formula $\,\vec{AM}=1/3(\vec{AC}+\vec{AB})\,$ is derived using the fact that medians are intersected at the point called *centroid* which divides each of the medians in the ratio $2:1$. You can also extend the triangle and get a parallelogram to make things very trivial. 
[image]

Comment: So we get the coordinates, where is the second part of the inequality?

Comment: I edited my answer + gave you a link for the centroid formula. Now it looks clearer. Hope it helps.